# JPA Property Expression - Match all children in OneToManyRelationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Requirement**

I have a simple OneToMany Relationship between two entities. I want to use JPA property expression to find Parent Entity with a condition which matches all children entities.

**Parent**

```
@Entity
public class PcSigningStatus {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "signingStatus")
    private List<PcSigningProcessEvent> signingProcessEvents = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
public class PcSigningProcessEvent {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProcessEventType phase;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SIGNING_STATUS_ID")
    private PcSigningStatus signingStatus;
}
```

**Parent Repository**

```
public interface SigningStatusRepo extends CrudRepository<PcSigningStatus, Long> {
    PcSigningStatus[] findBySigningProcessEvents_PhaseNot(ProcessEventType phase);
}
```

**Issue**

Suppose I only have 1 parent entity in database with 2 child entities containing different value of **phase**. The above query returns the same parent multiple times depending on the number of children it does not match the value of **phase** in. I need help in finding a way that Parent entity is returned only if the **phase** is not present in all the children entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found no way of doing this with property expression, and had to use Native Query instead.

**Soltution**

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT ss.* FROM PARENT_TABLE ss\n" +
            "left join CHILD_TABLE spe\n" +
            "ON ss.ID= spe.SIGNING_STATUS_ID\n" +
            "and spe.phase IN ('Value1', 'Value2')\n" +
            "where spe.ID is null", nativeQuery = true)
    PARENT_ENTITY[] customQuery();
```

This will return all parent entities whose children's property **phase** don't have any one of the value 'Value1' or 'Value2' or both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use @Query for this?

Comment: That's the purpose of Property expression so that you don't have to write manual queries, plus only @Query don't do anything, try to provide a valid query if you can

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your question :) But you can try add distinct flag using `Distinct` mentioned in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Edited: or you can use Query something like

```
SELECT * FROM PcSigningProcessEvent WHERE PcSigningProcessEvent.id NOT IN (SELECT SIGNING_STATUS_ID FROM PcSigningProcessEvent WHERE phase = ?)
```